# Locking a React Native App After an Amount of Time

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on a React Native application which shows a pincode screen upon login and each time the app is started (no longer active in the background). I would like to display this pincode screen each time a user leaves the app in the background longer than 5 minutes. This app will be deployed on Android and iOS.

Looking at search results shows me options for third-party libraries that may offer this functionality. Is there a way to do this without needing to resort to third-party tooling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to implement `AppState` change event

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', onAppStateChange);

let lastTimestamp = 0;
function onAppStateChange(state) {
  if (state === 'background') {
    // Store current time
    lastTimestamp = Date.now();
  } else if (state === 'active') {
    if (Date.now - lastTimestamp > 5 * 60 * 1000) {
       // Show you pin code screen
    }
  }
}

// Remember to remove listener when you don't need it
AppState.removeEventListener('change', onAppStateChange);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PanResponder` 
import PanResponder from react-native
Add below inside your constructor

```
this. panResponser = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {
            let now = new Date().getTime();
            if (now < your_desired_expiry_time) {
                let newTime = new Date().getTime() + your_logout_time_in_milliseconds;
                //now you can update your expiry time with newTime
            }
            else {
                //go back to login
            }
        }
    })
```

**Usage**

```
<View {...this.panResponser.panHandlers}>

   ...your other views
</View>
```